# using icomoon with SVGs from illustrator cc

Tags: svg, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I've fallowed the video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oQCkxfK5Ho#t=236

I'm exporting svg from Illustrator CC (I've tried almost all variations of options) but always get this message:
"Please select images or fonts in SVG, or JSONs exported by IcoMoon."
I've tried other apps (fontello, fontastic, etc) but get the same error ("unknown format").

my svg (one of them looks something like this):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="30.6px" height="28.3px" viewBox="0 0 30.6 28.3" enable-background="new 0 0 30.6 28.3" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="checkbox-12-icon" d="M27.4,9.1c0.6,1.6,0.9,3.3,0.9,5c0,7.8-6.3,14.2-14.2,14.2C6.3,28.3,0,22,0,14.2C0,6.3,6.3,0,14.2,0
c3.3,0,6.4,1.1,8.8,3c-0.8,0.6-1.7,1.3-2.5,2c-1.8-1.3-4-2-6.3-2c-3,0-5.8,1.2-7.9,3.3c-2.1,2.1-3.3,4.9-3.3,7.9
c0,3,1.2,5.8,3.3,7.9c2.1,2.1,4.9,3.3,7.9,3.3c3,0,5.8-1.2,7.9-3.3c2.1-2.1,3.3-4.9,3.3-7.9c0-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.2-2.1
C25.9,11,26.6,10,27.4,9.1z M16,22.2c5.5-9.9,9.4-15,14.6-19.6L30,1.1C23.6,5,20.2,8,15,13.9c-2.8-2-4.3-2.9-6.8-4.1l-2.1,1.9
C10.3,15.7,12.6,18.2,16,22.2z"/>
</svg>
```

I've spent 2 days on this but can't figure out **What am I missing ??**

Answer (score 0):

After trying this for 2 days I've changed my browser to Chrome and it worked (without any error message).

So that has been a Firefox thing. (Damn you Mozilla !)